# H2 createTcpServer() does not create server?

Tags: java, database, h2, creation

after reading the H2 [documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#creating_new_databases), I wrote this simple application to create a H2 database in a local directory:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

    String path = "C:/Temp/H2/";
    File fpath = new File(path);

    fpath.mkdirs();
    FileUtils.recursiveDelete(fpath);

    String dbName = "tata";
    String connection = "jdbc:h2:file:" + path + dbName;

    Server server = Server.createTcpServer(connection);

    server.start();
    server.stop();

}
```

This program runs fine, but when I check in the target directory, the database is not there... (i am using release 1.3.161)

Comment: You should use `Server.createTcpServer()`

Comment: @Thomas but isn't it what I did?

Comment: @JVestry no, you use `Server.createTcpServer(connection)` not `Server.createTcpServer()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually access the database, files are created lazily:

```
server.start();
DriverManager.getConnection(connection);
server.stop();
```

Added line in the middle creates `tata.h2.db` file where expected (tested with 1.3.155).

Comment: Yes, and actually the server doesn't need to know about the database, that means use `Server.createTcpServer()`;

Comment: @Thomas Sorry, this is ambiguous, what do you mean by "the server does not need to know about the database"? The documentation is hard to interprete. It does not provide enough information for proper interpretation.

Comment: @JVestry I will try to improve the documentation.