# Run H2 in server mode and store data to file

Tags: h2

It is very easy and *well* documentented how to run H2 in server mode. Just code:

```
Server.createTcpServer().start();
```

Very easy. But I'm unable to find an answer on:

- how to give the created database an other name than 'test', because this is the default name.
- how to persist the data. As it seems, this way the server starts an in-memory DB. But what I'm looking for is something that persists the data permanently.

Any idea?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8068843/2675154) post on SO helps at least partially...

Answer (score 3):

As described in [*Connecting to a Database using JDBC*](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#connecting_using_jdbc), the database file name may be specified in the database URL, for example

```
jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/src/java/MyDatabase;IFEXISTS=TRUE
```

Data will be stored in the file `MyDatabase,h2.db`.

See [*Opening a Database Only if it Already Exists*](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#database_only_if_exists) for the effect of specifying `;IFEXISTS=TRUE`. Compare the URL with these embedded mode [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2443685/230513).

Addendum: *Where will you give this URL*?

Once the server is started, you can connect to the running database by passing the URL to your preferred client, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2761825/230513), or programmatically via `java.sql.Connection`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24762078/230513).

Comment: I read this many times. But where will you give this URL in. Take a look into the API I only find this properties

    Supported options are: -tcpPort, -tcpSSL, -tcpPassword, -tcpAllowOthers, -tcpDaemon, -trace, -ifExists, -baseDir, -key. See the main method for details.

Additionally I can see the in main that '-properties <dir>' are possible, but I'm unable to find any description of properties. And from the API Server has only a method getURL, not a setURL.

I don't know what to do.

Comment: @AndreasRiedel: The easiest way is to browse `http://localhost:8082`, as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2761825/230513); more above.

Answer (score 2):

After an other day and switch to derby I find a solution for this problem. I don't know why this is not handled by the H2 documention, but ok.
First at all. For me the connection url and the physical location of the DB-Files are different things. And I don't like this file things, because I want to take a look in the db on the fly.

So, whats to is this

```
private Server startDb() {
    Server retVal = null;

    try {
        final String userDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        // System.setProperty("h2.baseDir", userDir + "/data/jumpstart");

        retVal = Server.createTcpServer("-baseDir", userDir + "/data/jumpstart");
        retVal.start();

        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/jumpstart", "sa", "sa");
        } finally {
            if (conn != null)
                conn.close();
        }
    } catch (final Exception ex) {

    }

    return retVal;
}
```

As you can see here, the files of the db will be stored in the directoy /data/jumpstart.

The URL of JDBC connect hide this detail. It only address the the DB with name jumpstart.

That it is.

HTH
  Andreas